# What is the difference between Example1 and Example2?

Tags: javascript, iife

Example 1:

```js
(function () {
  let encryptionKey = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1)*4);
  console.log (encryptionKey >= 6);
})();
    
console.log(encryptionKey);    //encryptionKey is not defined
```

Example 2:

```js
(function () {
  encryptionKey = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1)*4);
  console.log (encryptionKey >= 6);
})();
  
console.log(encryptionKey);   //encryptionKey is logged in the console without any errors
```

Trying to find out why the value is displayed in the second example.

Comment: Read about scoping in relation to javascript variables, particularly how it applies to `let`

Comment: Also, [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: Second one you have created a global variable, so can be seen outside the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope of the variables declared without `var`/`let`/`const` keywords become global irrespective of where it is declared. Global variables can be accessed from anywhere in the web page.